# Gunicorn, Django, and slow loading code...?

Tags: django, gunicorn

My code uses **matplotlib** which takes a good second or two to load (it seems).  The problem is that when I send `kill -HUP <pid>` to Gunicorn, that the next request to Gunicorn loads the actual code at request time which takes a good second or two.

I'd like to not force the user to wait that second or two.  I've been playing around with hitting the website with `urllib2.urlopen()` and forcing some instances to load the code, but I cannot guarantee that all workers have loaded the code.

How can I work around the backend loading the code at request time vs when its started?  Do I put the offending slow loading modules in settings.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gunicorn has some pretty awesome configuration.  Was browsing around a git clone of their source and found an example_config.py which has a "post_fork" which got me thinking.  After some poking around the source a bit more, I came up with this solution.

```
% gunicorn_django -c path/to/gunicorn_conf.py path/to/settings.py
```

Where gunicorn_conf.py has this function:

```
def post_fork(server, worker):
    server.log.info("%s: Worker spawned" % worker.pid)

    from gunicorn.workers.sync import SyncWorker
    class SyncWorkerPreload(SyncWorker):
        def run(self):
            pass

        def init_process(self):
            super(SyncWorkerPreload, self).init_process()
            from django.db.models.loading import get_apps
            get_apps()
            server.log.info('%s: App loaded' % self.pid)
            super(SyncWorkerPreload, self).run()

    worker.__class__ = SyncWorkerPreload
```

Hope that helps someone google'ing to find this hint.

Pretty awesome that Gunicorn was flexible enough to allow for this!

**UPDATE:** updated code, simply loading modules in settings sometimes breaks due to the way django loads modules I assume... this new code monkey patches gunicorn to load the modules at a "safe" time... hopefully

**UPDATE:** gunicorn 0.12.1 fixes this issue

Comment: Hi @dlamotte, do you have to pass any flag to gunicorn so that the code is loaded automatically? You mention this issue has been fixed in 0.12.1, but I'm still experiencing slow performance at load time. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like it's due to Django's delayed imports on some modules. I'd either go with settings.py or maybe the specific app's urls.py to get them imported when the worker boots.